# using regular expression pattern replace to convert cents to dollars

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

am fairly new to regex and, have this situation where I store price in cents but need to search them by using the dollar equivalent. Am trying to write a pattern replacer that converts cents to dollars (basically divide by 100)

Eg:

```
2349 -> 23.49
18   -> .18
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what about `1`? Then you would need to manufacture a zero: `1` --> `.01`. Regex alone can't do this in one pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be MUCH easier ways of doing this.

**RegEx:**

\b(?\d*?)(?\d{1,2})\b

First group is the $ and the second group is the cents.

**Replace RegEx:**

${dollar}.${cent}

This will search for any numbers (any length) in a string and split it in $ and cents.

**Explain:**

\b : word boundry

\d : digit

*? : lazy select (as few matches as possible)

{1,2} : match one or two characters. Will fill this before the lazy *? selection

( ) : grouping

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not a good tool for this. Using the math built in to your language of choice will end up causing less pain and gnashing of teeth.

**Edit**

If you do try to match you'll have to deal with single digit values which would need to be padded with zeros. If you don't have to worry about that you can match the cents with:

```
(\d*)(\d\d)
```

Then replace with \1.\2

Comment: I agree. But, am indexing the values in elasticsearch and, to support searching with dollars, i'd need to tokenize the cents to dollars and the only way that elasticsearch supports is through a pattern replacer